# scrollbar inside jquery UI dialog crashes IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

to see this you can go

- here: http://mrgsp.md:8080/prodinner
- click on "host a dinner" and make your browser small enough so that you would get scrollbars in the UI dialog
- now try scrolling, IE will crash

(do this using IE8 or IE9 with IE8 browsder mode (F12 select IE8 browser mode) )

that dialog is filled with content via ajax (in case that matters)

Comment: I think this is more of a IE bug than a jquery one. If you cannot find any solutions to it then perhaps you should file a error report with microsoft.

Comment: @Tomas IE has lots of bugs and it will always have, I just want to know if there may be some workarounds

Comment: I think this is related to your little dog with the ajax calls etc, can you humour me and completely take out the html/js for that item.

Comment: @ufjamaflip just tried this, same thing, crashes when try to scroll

Comment: Sorry to ask again but it's a process, can you remove "all" content from the dialog?

Comment: @ufjamaflip yes of course, you could even do this with firebug, not sure if it possible with IE dev tool, and if you will remove the content from the inside you will loose the scrollbars as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is

```
height:100%
```

on body and html tags, removing either of them will help.

and in the case that you need an alternative

```
$(function () {
     var $window = $(window);
     var $html = $('html');
     $window.resize(function () {
         $html.width($window.width());
         $html.height($window.height());
     });
 });
```

using this method you can keep height on body.

Comment: how did you knew that ? that the height on html makes ie crash when scrolling inside UI dialog

Comment: @Omu actually what i did know, and what i already know is that the most complicated thing about creating a software is how its component are connected to each other(here it's IE), for example here I'd to check and test height and overflow property on all target element parents, and finally i get to body and html.I'm so glad to help you Omu.

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer seems appropriate for the problem, I had a similar issue and tracked it down to the  element that I was loading the jQueryUI into.  Basically, I had a shorthand version

```
<div id="someID" />
```

- this worked fine in Chrome but made IE8 crash

changing it to:

```
<div id="someID"></div>
```

- fixed it.

Hope this is helpful in case anyone else comes across this question.